# How to declare a Hierachic grid based on List item in parent properties?

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

Given an object Movie with a property Actors that is a list of Actor.
How to display Actors in a colapsible hierachical grid?

Like: 
[image: Img Here]

RadGrid Declaration:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">        
        <MasterTableView PageSize="10" DataKeyNames="Actors" GroupsDefaultExpanded="False">
            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView >                        

                </telerik:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>
        </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

In Code Behind:

```
RadGrid1.DataSource = ServiceLike.GetMovies();

public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genres { get; set; }
    public Actor[] Actors { get; set; }
}
public class Actor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class ServiceLike
{

    public static Movie[] GetMovies()
    {
        return new[]{
            new Movie{
                Id =1,
                Genres ="",
                Title ="First",
                Actors= new []{
                    new Actor{ Name= "Actor1" },
                }
            },
            new Movie{Id=2, Genres="", Title="Second",
                Actors= new []{
                    new Actor{ Name= "Foo" },
                    new Actor{ Name= "Bar" },
                }
            },
            new Movie{Id=3, Genres="", Title="Third",
                Actors= new []{
                    new Actor{ Name= "Joe" },
                    new Actor{ Name= "Monika" },
                    new Actor{ Name= "Ross" },
                }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

The aim here is to limit the call to the `GetMovies()` Method in the DetailTable.

---

This is a simplification of my issue:
Displaying a list as a sub grid without spamming the service that provides the object containning this list. Movie and Actor are exemple class not related to the real data. The grid declaration is a clean try, As telerik can be a lot of try and fail I provided a clean try than any of the numerous try as they can be missleading.

Answer (score 0):

DataKeyNames can only contain a [Bindable Property Types](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/bindable-property-types). List, Array, or such will not work.

Also, the DataKeyNames are meant to provide with a value that can be used to identify the object. In this case, the Id of the Movie would be the best to use:

```xml
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" 
    OnDetailTableDataBind="RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind">
    <MasterTableView PageSize="10" DataKeyNames="Id" GroupsDefaultExpanded="False">
        <DetailTables>
            <telerik:GridTableView>
            </telerik:GridTableView>
        </DetailTables>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

You could, of course use the id of a child item as the Unique identifier if it had a bindable property.

```
DataKeyNames="Actor.Id"
```

In case its an array, you'd need to access the item by it's array index. Even use multiple Actor's ID to act as Identifier for a row. That could help find the Movie by actors id.

```
DataKeyNames="Actors[0].Id, Actors[1].Id, Actors[3].Id"
```

This, however is not practical and the application would error out if it tries to access the array item by an index that does not exist.

To avoid any unexpected behavior caused by binding, use [Advanced Data-binding (Using NeedDataSource Event)](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/server-side-binding/advanced-data-binding-(using-needdatasource-event)) to bind data to RadGrid. Perhaps, you are already using it. I mention it in case.

```cs
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsFromDetailTable) RadGrid1.DataSource = ServiceLike.GetMovies();
}
```

For binding data to the child tables programmatically, you may use the DetailTableDataBind event. ([Hierarchical data-binding using DetailTableDataBind event](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/hierarchical-grid-types-and-load-modes/hierarchical-data-binding-using-detailtabledatabind-event)). This will fire as soon as you expand a Grid row, and in the event arguments, you'll have access to the Child table object. 
Use that to traverse up the Object tree and access its parents. ([Accessing Cells and Rows](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows))

```cs
protected void RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
{
    GridTableView tableView = e.DetailTableView;
    GridNestedViewItem nestedViewItem = tableView.NamingContainer as GridNestedViewItem;
    GridDataItem parentItem = nestedViewItem.ParentItem;

    e.DetailTableView.DataSource = Array.Find(ServiceLike.GetMovies(), item => item.Id == (int)parentItem.GetDataKeyValue("Id")).Actors;
}
```

If all done correctly, the results would look like this:
[image]